# Create a fixed menu bar

Tags: android

I got to create a fixed menubar on the top of the screen with two image buttons in it.
How can i do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `RelativeLayout` and use the property `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` for the buttons.

See the code snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
 <Button 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>   
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
    />      
    <!-- your rest of layout elements -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can i make such menu bar transparent on the text on which i lay this relative layout ?

Comment: @User598331 : yes you can use **`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`** property for the layout to make it transparent.